# How do I call a method from a different class in my current class. AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, methods, flash-cs4

I have a class, my document class, called SilkRoadTweeter.as
I also have a class called User.as
In my User class I need to call a method called nonce()
I have tried this,

```
trace(SilkRoadTweeter(root).nonce());
```

But I get the error,

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

Comment: You should add more details about your classes.

Answer (score 1):

Edit

I actually forgot one of the most important one, you could dispatch en event!

```
     //In the Document class
     var user:User = new User();
     user.addEventListener( "nonce" , nonceEventListener );

     //define your listener
     private function nonceEventListener(event:Event):void
     {
        user.result = this.nonce();
     }

     //In the User class
     public function result(value:Number):void
     {
        //here you deal the generated Number
      }

      //somewhere in the Class
     this.dispatch( new Event("nonce") );
```

End of Edit

You should pass your instance of SilkRoadTweeter in the User class

For instance:

```
    //In the Document class
    var user:User = new User( this );

    //In the User class
    var srt:SilkRoadTweeter;

    public function User( srt:SilkRoadTweeter )
    { 
       this.srt = srt;
       srt.nonce();
    }
```

If the User class instance is added as a child of the SilkRoadTweeter class, you could also 
do this

```
    //In the User class
    var srt:SilkRoadTweeter;

    public function User()
    { 
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED , addedListener );
    }

    protected function addedListener(event:Event ):void
    {
         srt = this.parent as SilkRoadTweeter;
         srt.nonce();
    }
```

Comment: Hey, sorry I don't think I was clear. I need to call nonce() and nonce() is in the document class (SilkRoadTweeter.as) but I need to call it from the other class User.as

Comment: I am about to go and try that now. All nonce() does is return a generated number. Is there no way just to call nonce() from User and just get the value?

Comment: And yes the user object is added as a child of SilkRoadTweeter

Answer (score 1):

You said that the nonce() function is in the SilkRoadTweeter class and you need to call it from the User class. You must have a reference to the SilkRoadTweeter in order to call functions on it. The error is saying it doesn't know what a SilkRoadTweeter is.  Using root to get a reference is messy in my opinion and should be avoided. I would suggest passing a reference to the User class when you create it. If that is not an option, making the function nonce() on the SilkRoadTweeter class static would solve your problem, so long as the function doesn't need to access non-static properties of the SilkRoadTweeter. You said all it does is return a generated number so I would guess it doesn't need to access non-static properties. I can elaborate further on what I've said if your still confused.

Comment: I will make nonce() a static function. But I do also have another function I want to call in SilkRoadTweeter from User called signRequest() that uses lots of different variables in the SilkRoadTweeter class. Then how would I do it?

Comment: If you're going to be doing a lot of function calls between the two classes I would suggest sending a reference to the User class when it is created. Code for creating an instance of the User class in the SilkRoadTweeter would look like this: var user : User = new User( this ); And the User class constructor would except a SilkRoadTweeter that you then can save off as private property and use to make the function calls.

Answer (score 0):

In this case "*root*" is probably null.
Try debugging it to check.

Comment: I feel really stupid saying this but I don't actually know what root is.

Comment: I am studying action script at University and I have used something similar to trace(SilkRoadTweeter(root).nonce());

Comment: Jordan's answer is best for you.  Static is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
trace(root is SilkRoadTweeter)
```

I have feeling you need to do:

```
trace((root.getChildAt(0) as SilkRoadTweeter).nonce());
```

Comment: trace(root is SilkRoadTweeter); traced nothing??